# Is the associative property of XOR provable or axiomatic?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I have been trying to prove (for my own entertainment) that XOR is associative.

However, having reduced $(p \oplus q ) \oplus r = p \oplus (q  \oplus r)$ to canonical form, so that the only logical operations are OR, AND; I end up having something that I cannot reduce without relying on the associative and distributive properties of AND and OR.

It seems rather redundant to prove that one logical operator has a certain property but rely on another to do so.

My question is: Is the associative property of XOR provable algebraically - or is it axiomatic? Does the truth table count as a proof?

EDIT: This is the table I came up with.

[image]

Comment: If you want to reduce it anyway to OR and AND, why is it so smelly to use their associativity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The truth table is enough, since truth tables provide a complete model theory for classical propositional logic.  You can show this by proving that any formula is equivalent to its [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) and then noting that truth tables are essentially a condensed representation of this DNF.

XOR is often defined using its truth table.

Comment: I added my truth table to the OP... Is that convertible to DNF?

Comment: @trideceth12: Yes, it's a ternary operator, with four clauses, one for each row ending with a 1 for the last column.  The first row is $\neg p \wedge \neg q \wedge r$, and you or all the clauses together to get the DNF.  This process must be described somewhere; I'll take a look.

Comment: @trideceth12: The best I saw was a YouTube video - you have to watch over 3 minutes to see what is going on, so maybe a question here is more useful.  Link - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpdDlsg4Cws

Answer (score 3):

Note that both $(p\oplus q)\oplus r$ and $p\oplus (q\oplus r)$ are true if and only if *odd number* of $p,q,r$'s are true.

Similarly, you can consider *sets* in place of logical statements, then AND corresponds to intersection and OR to union, NOT to complement, and using
$$p\oplus q = (p \land \lnot q ) \lor (q\land \lnot p) $$
we get
$$ A\oplus B = (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A) $$
this is the *symmetric difference* of sets, and $x\in A_1\oplus..\oplus A_n$ iff $x$ is element of exactly an odd number of $A_i$'s.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *formal* proof according to the definition of proof used in modern logic, then you need some set of axioms or rules of inference from which a proof can get written.

Informally, the truth table indicates associativity of XOR, or equivalently that {[(p⊕q)⊕r]=[p⊕(q⊕r)]} qualifies as a tautology, where "=" indicates the operation of logical equivalence.  By the completeness metatheorem (every tautology is a theorem) of really any system of classical propositional logic that you probably will encounter, it follows that {[(p⊕q)⊕r]=[p⊕(q⊕r)]} qualifies as a theorem.  So, the truth table does qualify as an informal proof that a theorem exists in the formal system.

Depending on the context, hardly anyone may care about writing or seeing a formal proof... though your computer might "consider" you crazy if you think you can give it an informal proof and it mean anything.

Comment: I care about it just because I like to know where things stand technically.

Comment: @trideceth12 From my reading, I think it fair to say that most logicians care that such a proof can in principle get written, but they usually care a lot less about seeing a formal proof or writing a formal proof.